# Converting MM to Inches - Javascript

Tags: javascript

how do I add Millimeters to inches to this? I'm trying to convert MM go inches. Here is my code Snippet.

```js
function cmConverter() {
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.cm.value / 2.54
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.cm.value / 30.48
}

function inchConverter() {
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.inch.value * 2.54
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.inch.value / 12
}

function feetConverter() {
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.feet.value * 30.48
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.feet.value * 12
}
```

```html
<form name="converter">
  Cm: <input type="text" name="cm" onChange="cmConverter()"><br /> 
  Inch: <input type="text" name="inch" onChange="inchConverter()"><br /> 
  Feet: <input type="text" name="feet" onChange="feetConverter()"><br />
 
  <input type="button" value="Convert!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please make an attempt at it and then if you have trouble, post the code that you tried.

Comment: there are 10mm to a cm - does that help?

Answer (score 2):

There are 10mm in a centimeter, so just divide the number of centimeters by 10 to convert to millimeters.

```js
function cmConverter() {
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.cm.value / 2.54
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.cm.value / 30.48
  document.convert.mm.value = document.convert.cm.value/10;
}

function inchConverter() {
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.inch.value * 2.54
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.inch.value / 12
  document.converter.mm.value = document.convert.inch.value*25.4;
}

function feetConverter() {
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.feet.value * 30.48
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.feet.value * 12
   document.converter.mm.value = document.convert.feet.value*304.8;
} 
function mmConverter() {
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.mm.value / 25.4
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.mm.value / 304.8;
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.mm.value * 10
}
```

```html
<form name="converter">
  Cm: <input type="text" name="cm" onChange="cmConverter()"><br /> 
  Inch: <input type="text" name="inch" onChange="inchConverter()"><br /> 
  Feet: <input type="text" name="feet" onChange="feetConverter()"><br />
  
 MM: <input type="text" name="mm" onChange="mmConverter()"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Convert!" />
</form>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I have suggested in my answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Add another input type in your html.

```
  Mm: <input type="text" name="mm" onChange="mmConverter()"><br />
```

And code for JavaScript

```
 function mmConverter() {
  document.converter.inch.value = document.converter.mm.value / 25.4
  document.converter.feet.value = document.converter.mm.value / 304.8
  document.converter.cm.value = document.converter.mm.value / 10

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertMmToInches(){
    var mm = document.getElementById('milli').value;
    var inches = mm/25.4;
    inches = inches.toPrecision(10);
    document.getElementById('result').value = inches;
}
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="milli" min="0" onKeyUp="convertMmToInches()"/>
        <input type="number" id="result"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are trying to do some thing like this - [[Millimeters to Inches]](https://mm-in-inches.com), hope this helps!